# Getting rid of spurious directories with tar -xzvf, while gunzipping

Tags: gzip, gunzip

I want to trim the path of the gunzipped tarball so that some "spurious" leading directories are excluded.  Let me explain with an example.

I have the following directory structure, as outputted by the `tree` command:

```
tree /tmp/gzip-expt

/tmp/gzip-expt
├── gunzip-dir
├── gzip-dir
└── repo
    └── src-tree
        ├── l1file.txt
        └── sub-dir
            └── l2file.txt

5 directories, 2 files
```

I want to gzip up src-tree in gzip-dir so this is what I do:

```
cd /tmp/gzip-expt/gzip-dir
tar -czvf file.tar.gz /tmp/gzip-expt/repo/src-tree
```

Subsequently I gunzip file.tar.gz in gunzip-dir so this is what I do:

```
cd /tmp/gzip-expt/gunzip-dir
tar -xzvf /tmp/gzip-expt/gzip-dir/file.tar.gz
```

`tree /tmp/gzip-expt/gunzip-dir` shows the following output:

```
/tmp/gzip-expt/gunzip-dir
└── tmp
    └── gzip-expt
        └── repo
            └── src-tree
                ├── l1file.txt
                └── sub-dir
                    └── l2file.txt
```

However, I would like `tree /tmp/gzip-expt/gunzip-dir` to show the following output:

```
/tmp/gzip-expt/gunzip-dir
└── src-tree
    ├── l1file.txt
    └── sub-dir
        └── l2file.txt
```

In other words, I don't want to see the "spurious" tmp/gzip-expt/repo part of the path.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to fix this when creating the archive or when extracting it. `tar` will use the full path to the files/directories that you give it on the command line.  You appear to be using the absolute path to the `src-tree` directory in your command.  Is this your intention? It would otherwise be easy to `cd` into `repo` and then just `tar` the `./src-tree` path there. I don't know if you need the full path in the archive for some other reason though.

Comment: You also mention both `zip` and `unzip`.  I don't think those tools are related to what you're currently doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks.  Your comment answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not spurious, it just stores exactly what it was told to store.

In particular, given the path `/tmp/gzip-expt/repo/src-tree`, it can't know which parts of the path should be kept, if the files should be stored as `/tmp/gzip-expt/repo/src-tree/l1file.txt`, or `src-tree/l1file.txt` or `l1file.txt` etc. It makes a difference when extracting the tarball, if the archive has the leading directory, it's created when extracting. If not, it's not.

Give `tar` a relative path, and have it run in the correct directory for the relative paths to work correctly:

```
cd /tmp/gzip-expt/repo
tar -czvf /tmp/gzip-expt/gzip-dir/file.tar.gz ./src-tree
```

or

```
cd /tmp/gzip-expt/gzip-dir
tar -C /tmp/gzip-expt/repo -czvf file.tar.gz ./src-tree
```

The GNU man page describes `-C` as:

> `-C`, `--directory=DIR`
> Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.

but as far as I can see, the file given by `-f` is still used from the directory `tar` was started in, even if `-C` is given first.

If you want to fix it on extraction, at least GNU tar has `--strip-components=N` which tells it to drop leading parts of the filenames. E.g. with `--strip-components=2`, a filename like `/tmp/gzip-expt/repo/src-tree/...` would be extracted as `repo/src-tree/...`.